# Attributive だろう

Tags: grammar, nuances, relative-clauses, copula

I came across this sentence (下町ロケット, p.239):

> 「どうだ、そろそろウチに戻ってこないか」
>   そんなことをいいはじめたのは、六十五歳を過ぎ、体力的な衰えを**感じはじめただろう頃だ**。

Meaning-wise, it seems hard to imagine it means anything other than 感じはじめた頃だろう. However, I wonder, is there is a slight difference in nuance, or something else that would have made the author choose this rare (at least I don't think I've seen it before) usage of だろう?

---

**和訳**

この文章に出くわしました：（下町ロケットp.239）

> 「どうだ、そろそろウチに戻ってこないか」
>   そんなことをいいはじめたのは、六十五歳を過ぎ、体力的な衰えを**感じはじめただろう頃だ**。

意味的には、「感じはじめた頃だろう」と同じだと思っていますが、これほど珍しい（少なくとも私は見たことのない）「だろう」の使い方をする理由（ニュアンスの違いなど）はありますか。

Comment: Makino's Intermediate Grammar Dictionary says that this use of だろう is not grammatical.Instead, であろうshould be used.

Comment: For completeness :) it makes sense to translate the quote to English. My possibly bad translation is: `"How about returning home soon?" he started saying after 65 years has passed and he started to feel that he probably becomes weaker.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is a slight difference in what the uncertainty is about:

> 1. … 六十五歳を過ぎ、<unsure>体力的な衰えを感じはじめた</unsure>**だろう**頃だ。
> 2. … <unsure>六十五歳を過ぎ、体力的な衰えを感じはじめた頃</unsure>**だろう**。

In #1, the uncertainty is less about the actual time frame, and more about what their physical condition had been. In #2, it seems that the uncertainty is mainly about the time frame.

Likewise, in the sentences below, #1 is unsure whether the children were hungry, while #2 is unsure whether these children had it worst:

> 1. いちばん大変だったのは、お腹が空いていた**であろう**子供たちだ。
> 2. いちばん大変だったのは、お腹が空いていた子供たち**であろう**。

---

I did not know that this use of `だろう` is technically incorrect and should be `であろう` instead (as brought up by xeta217 in the comments). I could also find [one page](http://www2.dokkyo.ac.jp/~japan/japanese/sub1/sub1-8.htm) online that agrees with this rule. However, there are probably [many](https://goo.gl/dQ2dg1) [other](https://goo.gl/HvYzDd) [books](https://goo.gl/Sd5096) that use phrases like だろう頃に, so it may be that this rule is not widely known, or debatable.

Comment: Extremely clearly put, thank you! As for the rule, well, I feel like any rule that is disagreeing with language used in a professionally edited novel written by a multiple-literary-award-winning author is probably some safely ignorable prescriptivism... :-)

Comment: Whether these children had it worst? To me the second sentence sounds like: "The top priority (いちばん大変だったの) is supposedly (であろう) children that were hungry." Or more literally: "the thing (の) that was (だった) very (大変) number one (いちばん)." What am I missing?

Comment: @yk7 Good question. The 大変 in this sentence means "difficult" as in having a hardship, not "very".